# How to achieve horizontal sorting with react-beautiful-dnd on multiple lines and without horizontal scroll?

Tags: reactjs, sorting, react-beautiful-dnd

I need to have all sortable elements listed on multiple lines and without horizontal scroll.
Look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-beautiful-dnd-horizontal-list-forked-smn1s?file=/index.js

Currently it is not achievable neither with:

```
direction="horizontal"
```

nor with:

```
direction="vertical"
```

Maybe I do not understand the package API well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `react-beautiful-dnd` doesn't support Grid layouts (multiple lines) – it's either a Vertical list or Horizontal list as it was [reported by Contributor to the library.](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/768#issuecomment-418201466)

Also in the same thread there is great example of React code that implements multiline drag-n-drop: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-drag-k3utz

It's functionality is based on:

- using CSS classes to get the Items from DOM
- using `dragStart` event to find out which item is being dragged now
- using `dragOver` event handler to find out over which of the items
  are we dragging
- rearranging items array using `Array.splice` function to place
  dragged Item on the place of the item over which it is dragged
- using CSS to position rearranged items in a grid, calculating every
  item 's row and column

I hope that this was helpful!